# Synchronized DNS-servers return different responses

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

I have two servers:

1. alpha.mydomain.net - 209.110.172.195
2. beta.mydomain.net - 185.169.74.16

Both of these servers come with WHM software installed.
With the help of WHM I configure DNS cluster on them.

So or DNS records created on alpha server are sync-ed to beta server.

When I execute this command

```
"nslookup webservices.mydomain.net ns1.mydomain.net"
```

I receive the following answer:

```
*** Can't find server name for address 209.110.172.195: Query refused
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  209.110.172.195

Name:    webservices.mydomain.net
Address:  185.169.74.16
```

I'd like to know why do I receive "Can't find server" error?

And when I query ns2 server (synced one) I receive different answer.
I thought answers must be identical due to these servers are synced.

```
nslookup webservices.mydomain.net ns2.mydomain.net
(root)  nameserver = G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
(root)  nameserver = F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
*** Can't find server name for address 185.169.74.16: No information
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  185.169.74.16

Name:    webservices.mydomain.net
Address:  185.169.74.16
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You've got so many different things going on in your attempt to diagnose this problem, I don't know where to start.  Well, I do, actually: http://squish.net/dnscheck/.  This tool is my number one go-to for diagnosing DNS problems.  It'll almost certainly show you the source of your problem, which I'm going to bet is that, your assertion that the servers are synced notwithstanding, they aren't.  Diagnosing WHM's insanities aren't my forte; personally, I think [control panels](http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2011/10/cpanel-university-youre-doing-it-all-wrong/) [suck](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/development/we_hate_plesk_and_cpanel).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't agree more with Womble's comment about control panels sucking. You need to remove as many layers as possible, which only server to hide reality and confuse the user (as proven by your question). Start by talking to the DNS service itself. You might also do a comparison of the zone files, paying particular attention to the serial numbers. Only then can you be really certain whether or not the systems are in sync.